# Dual Boot change to UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I currently have a dual boot setup where I have Windows 10 on one disk and ubuntu on another. This was installed in CSM mode, not UEFI. It works great, when I start my PC I can select Ubuntu or Windows with the GRUB bootloader. Now I wanted to get ready for Windows 11, one requirement for Windows 11 is to enable "Secure Boot". In order to enable that I had to change to UEFI. The issue is, that with UEFI I cannot boot Ubuntu. In the boot options it only shows "Windowsbootmanager" and the only disk I can select is the one with windows on it. After switching back to CSM mode I can access windows and ubuntu.

Side notes from my research:

- My `/boot/efi` directory is empty.
- `grub-install --version` gave me: `grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.13`

After following instructions from the answers (creating a partition and using boot repair):

Now I see two options in my BIOS/UEFI, the `Windows Boot Manager (Samsung SSD EVO 250GB)` and `ubuntu (Samsung SSD EVO 250GB)` . If I select Ubuntu as first bootoption I receive the following error screen:
[Ubuntu GRUB Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j8aa.jpg)
Now it is not possible anymore to boot ubuntu. Even if I switch back to CSM.

Here is the pastebin from boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4qhwYQt8k8/

I wonder if I have to convert the disk with ubuntu on it from MBR to GPT partition table. If so, how can I do it? I found the tool gdsik but as mentioned, my ubuntu doesn't boot anymore.

Comment: We got you covered: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: You should post the pastebin URL.

Comment: Here is the pastebin url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4qhwYQt8k8/

Comment: I solved my issues using gdisk from the bootrepair system terminal to change from MBR to GPT. Recreated the efi partition, did bootrepair again and voila, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI):

> **Converting Ubuntu into UEFI or Legacy mode**
>
> Note: Do not follow this procedure if your computer is already booting correctly. Use this procedure only if you believe you've accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and you want it to boot in UEFI/UEFI mode.
>
> - Start [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.
> - If you do not see a "Separate/boot/efi partition`" line, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an UEFI partition (see the "Creating an UEFI partition" paragraph above).
> - If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.
> - Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in UEFI mode (see the [Set up the BIOS in UEFI or Legacy mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Setup_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode) paragraph above).

Skip 1 and 2 and go straight for "Creating an UEFI partition"

> An ESP can be created via a recent version of [GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) (the Gparted version included from the Live session is OK), and must have the following attributes:
>
> - Mount point: /boot/efi (remark: no need to set this mount point when using the manual partitioning, the Ubuntu installer will detect it automatically)
>
> ```
> Size: minimum 100Mib. 200MiB recommended.
> Type: FAT32
> Other: needs a "boot" flag.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed your steps:
1. Created new partition
2. Booted from USB with Boot-Repair
3. Tried the boot repair

Edited my question to include new info.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get the PC to use the TPM module for Windows 11 upgrade, so also needed UEFI boot.

The PC had no option to boot from USB, so I copied the Linux .iso installation file with dd command from a USB to the swap partition. The `swapoff` command had to be run first. Then did system reboot and firmware startup menu had a new choice. When selected, the installation disk booted from the old swap partition. From there, the installation was done to the current Linux partition to rewrite the UEFI information. After that, the Legacy boot option was reset in the BIOS.

The system booted to windows by default. When system was rebooted and the Ubuntu UEFI boot manager selected, the system started Linux.